# How to get epoch time in shell script (for ksh)?

Tags: ksh

How to get epoch time in shell script (for ksh)?
I am interested in getting epoch time for the start of day (so e.g. now is July 28th, 2011 ~ 14:25:00 EST, I need time at midnight).

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU date,

```
epoch=$( date -d 00:00 +%s )
```

Otherwise, if you have tclsh,

```
epoch=$( echo 'puts [clock scan 00:00]' | tclsh )
```

Otherwise,

```
epoch=$( perl -MTime::Local -le 'print timelocal(0,0,0,(localtime)[3..8])' )
```

Answer (score 1):

ksh's `printf '%(fmt)T'` (the `(fmt)` part is optional) supports time calculating. For example:

```
$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01

$ printf '%T\n' now
Sat Aug  5 20:15:58 CST 2023

$ printf '%T\n' '2 days ago'
Thu Aug  3 20:16:06 CST 2023

$ printf '%T\n' 'midnight today'
Sat Aug  5 00:00:00 CST 2023
```