# Date difference in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I have two dates, 
for example
Mon Feb 15 00:03:25 GMT 2016
Tue Feb 16 00:00:15 GMT 2016

I need to calculate the difference in hours/minute in ksh unix.

How can be done it, can someone help here

Comment: Does this do what you want? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114925/korn-shell-show-elapsed-time-in-a-specific-format

Comment: Without GNU date you need to convert both dates to EPOCH, and convert to difference like the links @Jerry gave. When you have Perl you might want to use epoch=$( perl -MTime::Local -le 'print timelocal(0,0,0,(localtime)[3..8])' ) given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863827/how-to-get-epoch-time-in-shell-script-for-ksh. Without Perl you might find something at http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/200495-how-convert-string-variable-into-date-epoch-ksh-hpux-machine.html .

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU date (from [GNU Core Utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)):

```
# convert dates to UNIX timestamps (seconds since 00:00 Jan 1 1970)
date1=$( date -d "Mon Feb 15 00:03:25 GMT 2016" +"%s" )
date2=$( date -d "Tue Feb 16 00:00:15 GMT 2016" +"%s" )

diff_seconds=$(( date2 - date1 )) # total seconds
diff_hours=$(( diff_seconds/60/60 )) # whole hours

# deduct whole hours from total seconds
diff_seconds=$(( diff_seconds - 60*60*diff_hours ))

diff_minutes=$(( diff_seconds/60 )) # remaining whole minutes

# deduct whole minutes from remaining seconds
diff_seconds=$(( diff_seconds - 60*diff_minutes ))

printf "%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds\n" \
  diff_hours diff_minutes diff_seconds
```